# Small dash in bibleref package

Tags: bibleref

I suppose not many users know this package, but...

I need to customise the dash indicating a number range in the package bibleref. Now it's long (24--30), I neeed it short (24-30).

I tried with

```
\renewcommand*{\BRvsep}{-}
```

but it had no effect. Perhaps it has something to do with the language?

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\unicodefont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newfontfamily\ItalicFont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newfontfamily\SlantedFont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\setmainfont[Ligatures      = TeX, 
            Numbers         = OldStyle,
            Contextuals=NoAlternate
            ]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                
    \setmainlanguage{italian}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=ancient,numerals=arabic]{greek}           
    \setotherlanguages{english,latin, french, german, greek}

\usepackage{bibleref}
        \renewcommand*{\biblerefindex}{\index[rif]}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=rif,title=Indice dei riferimenti biblici, columns=2]


\begin{document}
pippo(Mt \ibiblechvs{Mt}(13:24-30))

\printindex[rif]    \label{indbib}      % Indice dei riferimenti biblici

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the documentation mentions it as `\BRvsep` that is actually about `\BRvrsep`.

So use

```
\renewcommand*{\BRvsep}{-}
```

instead. (I found this by searching for how BRvsep was used in the source.)

Comment: thanks for showing us the typo. I have corrected in a new version, just sent in the CTAN.